# sales force inner join Query is not Working?

Tags: c#, join, wsdl, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am using sales force WSDL file for getting data from sales force. Here query based execution i am using . But Select Query record is working but Inner join is not working.

**My Inner Join Query :**  SELECT LoginIp.UsersId, UserLogin.UserId 
FROM ( LoginIp INNER JOIN UserLogin ON LoginIp.UsersId = UserLogin.UserId)

**My Select Query :** SELECT LoginIp.UsersId FROM LoginIp

**Code :**

```
  public dynamic Execute(string queryString)
  {
     QueryResult qr = this._svc.query(queryString);
     sObject[] records = qr.records;
     return records;
  }
```

**Error :**  MALFORMED_QUERY: FROM ( LoginIp INNER JOIN UserLogin ERROR at Row:2:Column:5unexpected token: '('

Comment: @mjwills SELECT LoginIp.UsersId, UserLogin.UserId FROM ( LoginIp INNER JOIN UserLogin ON LoginIp.UsersId = UserLogin.UserId)

Comment: @mjwills I am Facing this error without ( and ) brackets "join: MALFORMED_QUERY: 
UserLogin.UserId FROM LoginIp INNER JOIN UserLogin ON LoginIp.UsersId
                                   ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:60
unexpected token: JOIN"

Comment: Does https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AQIFIA4 help?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce does not support all SQL statements. Please refrain from using `INNER JOIN`.

For more information pleas refer to the SOQL documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm

The LoginIp object model looks like this:

```
global class LoginIp extends SObject 
{
    global String ChallengeMethod;
    global Datetime ChallengeSentDate;
    global Datetime CreatedDate;
    global Boolean IsAuthenticated;
    global SObjectType SObjectType;
    global String SourceIp;
    global User Users;
    global Id UsersId;

    global LoginIp() {}
}
```

For you to achieve the required result please use the below SOQL Query:

`SELECT LoginIp.UsersId, Users.Id FROM LoginIp`